# Remove padding below video player

Tags: css

In the following layout, there is some padding that appears just below the video player:

```
<div class="furlHtmlCont">
   <div style="display: table;">
      <video controls="" autoplay="" class="furlHtml5Video">
          <source type="video/mp4" src="https://dwknz3zfy9iu1.cloudfront.net/uscenes_h-264_hd_test.mp4">
      </video>
   </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.furlHtml5Video {
    max-width: 300px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}

.furlHtmlCont {
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px #c0c0c0;
    border-left: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Deepview/L5mhyg2f/12/

If I remove the borders and box-shadow, the white padding disappears. Is there a way to keep that but avoid the padding at the bottom?

UPDATE: By setting `display: block` on the furlHtml5Video css class, it will get rid of the padding. Still, if there is another way of doing it other than this, that would be great because under certain conditions I need to have it a table.

Comment: Maybe you can use media query. By default you set to `display:block` and set to `display:table` based on certain condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `div` that wrap `video` into it which is display as `table`, so you could change the display of child element i.e. video or `.furlHtml5Video` to `table-cell` or change it's vertical-align as `top` to remove `padding` at `bottom` of video player,

```css
.furlHtml5Video {
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  display: table-cell; /*vertical-align:top*/
}

.furlHtmlCont {
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #c0c0c0;
  border-left: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="furlHtmlCont">
  <div style="display: table;">
    <video controls="" autoplay="" class="furlHtml5Video">
      <source type="video/mp4" src="https://dwknz3zfy9iu1.cloudfront.net/uscenes_h-264_hd_test.mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @AndroidDev You could even do that just by using display:table and no need to an extra div to wrap video tag, https://jsfiddle.net/5s3b7fj8/

Comment: The extra div is needed for other stuff that I left out for the sake of simplicity. But your idea using table-cell does work. Thanks a million!

Comment: Welcome @AndroidDev :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can set `font-size: 0;` to your `video`'s parent `div` i.e your `.furlHtmlCont` class.

```css
.furlHtml5Video {
  max-width: 300px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.furlHtmlCont {
  font-size: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  box-shadow: 0 0 8px #c0c0c0;
  border-left: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-right: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="furlHtmlCont">
  <div style="display: table;">
    <video controls="" autoplay="" class="furlHtml5Video">
          <source type="video/mp4" src="https://dwknz3zfy9iu1.cloudfront.net/uscenes_h-264_hd_test.mp4">
      </video>
  </div>
</div>
```